# Mysterious popups appearing for split second in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Recently I've noticed that my Chrome exibits this strange behaviour. There is what seems to be a popup window, that is opened and closed after just a few miliseconds. This happens every now and then - I couldn't find a pattern. It is not pop-under ad - there is no window left afterwards. What could this be and where should I start debugging this?

Here is a list of extensions I have currently enabled: https://gist.github.com/tomasfejfar/4fd23d04d5feda6cd6b068c0421f8cc4

**Update:** I do not have Office 365 installed.

**Update:** I experience this while browsing all kinds of webpages. Both trusted (slack, google) and general (random website with tutorial).

Comment: Why are you sure it's a Chrome window? Do you have Office from an Office 365 subscription installed?

Comment: Good question. I am not sure. It's just that I only noticed it while using chrome.

Comment: Yes, I'm noticing the same thing when I'm using Chrome. Happens across computers, persists between reboots and relaunches of Chrome. No idea what it is.

Comment: Oh, and my list of extensions has zero intersections with yours.

Comment: Please let me know here if you manage to find the root cause.

Comment: When do you experience this behaviour? Is it while browsing trusted websites? or websites that contain a lot of ads and pop-ups? I have seen this happen a lot. There are certain ads that are being blocked either by your adblock or any antimalware/antivirus. There is nothing to worry about. The specific ads are being blocked and closed immediately, instead of running in the background

Comment: Try disabling your adblock and/or antivirus and/or pop up blocker, and see if they stay up.

Comment: Try tracking processes using PE. http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/list-running-processes-and-their-creation-times/

Comment: Any luck finding the cause? I'm experiencing these mysterious popups too. The only extension we have in common is Save to Pocket.